# ADF Delta lake not saving deletes

Tags: azure-data-factory

A Mapping dataflow in ADF should delete rows based on an Alter transformation.

Even though the debug sessions says it should be deleted, it is not deleted from the Delta Lake.

[image]

[image]

Are you able to figure out what happens?

Comment: I too have the same issue. Were you able to resolve this ?

Comment: No I am not sure how to setup a pipeline that handles upserts and deletes...

Comment: Keeping them in separate data flows works well i.e. one for upsert and another for deletes. But having multiple Alter row transformations in one single data flow, I was facing certain issues with Spark clusters for which have raised a ticket with MS.

Comment: @ManiK thanks for your answer. Yes, I could imagine that conflicts would arrive when trying to write/delete in the same Mapping data flow.
Still if anyone has an example of af combined Upsert/delete mapping data flow please let me know.

Comment: One quick thing to check - did you define your write order for sinks in your mapping data flow i.e. upserts to be write order 1 and then deletes as 2 ?

Comment: I actually have not made a complete flow with Upsert and Deletes. I was not sure what the besy strategy was.